# ¿Se puede descargar los datos de una visualización de PowerBi a una base de datos?

Tags: python, sql-server, powerbi

Por el volumen de datos, millones de filas, es imposible descargarlo por los medios convencionales de powerBi de una manera eficiente. ¿Es posible conectar los datos de una visualización de PowerBi a una base de datos o a python, sin tener que descargarlo y volverlos a cargar en un excel?

Comment: Que haz avanzado? que llevas? tienes algún código de Avance?

Answer (score 1):

Sí, es posible conectar los datos de una visualización de Power BI a una base de datos o a Python. Hay varias formas de hacerlo:

Opción 1. Exportar a un archivo csv: Puedes exportar los datos a un archivo CSV y luego cargarlo en una base de datos o en Python. Para hacer esto, ve a "Archivo" -> "Exportar" -> "Datos" y selecciona "CSV".

Opción 2. Utilizar Power BI API: Power BI ofrece una API que permite programáticamente acceder a los datos de una visualización de Power BI. Puedes usar la API de Power BI en Python para conectarte a tus datos y realizar análisis.

Opción 3. Conectar a una base de datos: Puedes conectar Power BI directamente a una base de datos. Luego, puedes usar los datos en la base de datos para crear tus visualizaciones. Para hacer esto, ve a "Obtener datos" -> "Base de datos" y selecciona la fuente de datos que deseas utilizar.

En cualquier caso, es importante que consideres el rendimiento y la escalabilidad de la solución dependiendo del volumen de datos que manejes. Puede ser necesario optimizar o dividir los datos para que la solución sea eficiente.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta rápida es negativa. Sólo con una licencia Premium o Premium por usuario puedes acceder de forma directa a los datos publicados en el servicio de Power BI.

Si este fuera tu caso, lo puedes hacer mediante la API [XMLA disponible](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/power-bi/admin/service-premium-connect-tools).